# Why do I receive a bash syntax error when amending output >> to a file from a nohup command?

Tags: linux

Why do I receive a bash syntax error when amending output >> to a file from a nohup command?

```
# sudo nohup php something.php &>>/tmp/output
-bash: syntax error near unexpected token `>'
```

I'm using red hat enterprise

Comment: `&>>` is a `bash-4`-ism to append both stdout and stderr to a file.  Older versions of bash and other shells do not have this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no reason to do that.  When you "nohup" a command and BG it, output will automatically be redirected to $HOME/nohup.out.  Even if it did work, you'd likely wind up with an empty file.

Comment: I need to direct the output to a particular file, not $HOME/nohup.out

Comment: In that case, do nohup mycommand >> output.file & <-- this will run the entire command, which is both the "mycommand" and the output to the file, and then BG it with &

Answer (score 3):

Remove the `&`, just use `>>` to amend to /tmp/output

Answer (score 1):

For bash `&>file` or `&>>file` means `redirect both stdout and stderr to file`. If you want put something to background, put an & as last character in the command line, after any possible redirection.